# Pass parameter to json.dumps()

Tags: python, json, flask

In my flask server, a user passes a parameter to the server via a POST request, which symbolizes an entity in the server (a file, or a database entry).

If the id passed with the parameter, does not exist in the server, the server responds with:

```
return make_response(json.dumps({'error_message': 'item does not exist'}), 400)
```

How can i pass parameters in `json.dumps()`?
What i want to do is display: `error_message: item XXXXXX does not exist`
Where XXXXXX is the id that is passed as parameter to the server in the POST request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For passing the parameter, one way you could do it is creating a formatted string, such as:

```
from flask import jsonify

value = # something

return make_response(jsonify("error message": "item {} does not exist".format(value)), 400)
```

Or you could do something like the following:

```
value = # something

data = {"error message": "item {} does not exist".format(value)}

return make_response(jsonify(data), 400)
```

And to note: use `jsonify` instead.

> This function wraps dumps() to add a few enhancements that make life easier. It turns the JSON output into a Response object with the application/json mimetype.

Comment: Thanks, but still, how do i pass the parameter?

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I misread what you was doing. I will edit my post for you.

Comment: Thank you, but in my question i state that i want to pass both the parameter and a message inside. So i know how to do each separately, but i don't know how to combine them.

Comment: In that case, this *possibly* could work: `"error message": "item {} does not exist".format(value)`.

Comment: Is it easy to modify the code in your answer to reflect that?